# changing my android app min sdk from api 8 to api 4 removes my overridependingtransition

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-1.6

the problem is that 1.6 version doesn't supprt override pending transition ang gives me errors,so I removed them but my app looks very ugly without. The question is how to make overridependingtransition work on 2.2 and higher versions supporting also 1.6 version? thanks for the replies

Comment: Question is why you would want to go "down" to sdk 1.6 given that >> 90% are on 2.2+

Comment: OverridePendingTransition supported from 5 API verison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the [Platform Versions](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) on the Android Developer website. There is less than 1% users on 1.6 and older.

But if you really have to support 1.6, have a look at the followings links on the Android Dev website :

- [Versioning Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html)
- [Supporting Different Platform Versions](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html)
- [Using the Version-Aware Component](http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/using-component.html)
- [Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)

Comment: in fact, it depend of what you really want : support the most of devices (from 2.3 to 4.1) or support also older platforms like 1.6 :-)